# ValueCAN3 CAN Message - Invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x80'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm an Test Engineer and amateur python writer and I'm facing a problem sending a command to my ValueCan3 Device, let me share a little bit of context of my problem.

I'm testing a product where the address of each unit is different so I need to retrieve the address from the UUT using CAN messages every time I test a unit. The problem is that address came as integer and I need to convert into a HEX then I need to concatenate into string and send it back to my ValueCAN3 Hardware, please see my code here:

```
# This is the way I'm retrieving the address "m.Data[7]" means 128 as integer.
address = m.Data[7] 
# This is how I convert my integer 128 into HEX which in this case is 0x80
address_hex = hex(address)
```

Then, I need to concatenate 0x80 into my CAN message

```
msg.ArbIDOrHeader = 0x18EF+(address_hex)+00
```

Message should look like this

```
msg.ArbIDOrHeader = 0x18EF12800
```

But I got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x80'
```

Please see an update:

```
address = 128
address_hex = hex(address)
msg = ics.SpyMessage()
msg.StatusBitField = ics.SPY_STATUS_XTD_FRAME
msg.ArbIDOrHeader = 0x18EF+int(address_hex)+00
msg.Data = (0xC0,0xAC,0x23, 0x05, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00) ## to Enabled Thermistor
msg.NetworkID = ics.NETID_HSCAN
ics.transmit_messages(device, msg)
time.sleep(5)
msgs, error_count = ics.get_messages(device)
```

Comment: If you are converting to hex, than inserting into the message, wouldn't the message be `0x18EF8000`?

Comment: Post a [mcve] that produces the error described.  We should be able to copy and run that code **with no changes**.

Comment: That said, either `msg.ArbIDOrHeader = 0x18EF0000 | (address << 8)` (produces integer with correct address), or `msg.ArbIDOrHeader = hex(0x18EF0000 | (address << 8))` (if you need it as an actual hexadecimal string) will work.

Comment: @James Thank you for stopping by, you are correct, the message should be 0x18EF8000

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thank you Mark, unfortunately, the code depends of my test setup.

Comment: Test setup doesn't matter.  Write `address = 128` and `header = <your math that causes the error>`.  Hard code the data you'd get from test hardware.  The math is the problem.  For example `int('0x80')` returns the error claimed, but isn't shown at all in your code.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Hola Mark, I have updated the post

Comment: That isn't a [mcve] and wouldn't produce the error claimed, but just use `msg.ArbIDOrHeader = 0x18EF0000 | (address << 8)`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thank you Mark, what you sent works just fine for a 128 address (HEX 0x80), but address is changing all the time, address is not a fixed value. 

I've trying to play with your suggesting with no success, I'll keep trying.